# How to replace a string with string containing multiple / characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to change the following string

```
FROM java_jre_8@sha256:92f22331226b9b3c43a15eeeb304dd7
```

to

```
FROM docker-registry.service.consul:5000/java_jre_8@sha256:92f22331226b9b3c43a15eeeb304dd7
```

but am having difficult with sed as a result of `/` character

> This is for a build server.

Comment: just escape it `sed 's/FROM java_jre_8@/FROM docker-registry.service.consul:5000\/java_jre_8@/' myfile`

Comment: You can use any character as the command separator in sed, just use `#` for example: `sed 's#FROM java_jre_8@#FROM docker-registry.service.consul:5000/java_jre_8@#'`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this.  The first is to escape each `/` in the string you're replacing:

```
sed 's/from/to with \/ ... /'
```

The other, more simple way is to use a delimiter other than `/`.   While most sed examples use `/` as a delimiter, you can use any character:

```
sed 's|from|to with / ...|'
```

Here, the `|` is the first character following `s`, and therefore sed knows to use this as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#` as the delimiter as it doesn't appear in your string (you can still use `/` but then you'll have to quote the actual `/`s that are part of the string).

```
sed "s#FROM java_jre_8@#FROM docker-registry.service.consul:5000/java_jre_8@#'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "FROM java_jre_8@sha256:92f22331226b9b3c43a15eeeb304dd7" | sed "s#FROM java_jre_8@#FROM docker-registry.service.consul:5000/java_jre_8@#"
FROM docker-registry.service.consul:5000/java_jre_8@sha256:92f22331226b9b3c43a15eeeb304dd7
```